# Why Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Item() throws exception on a key not found while IDictionary.Item() should not?

Tags: c#, dictionary, symbol-table

That's seems strange to me that the [Dictionary.Item()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx) method throws KeyNotFoundException while [IDictionary.Item()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.item.aspx) does not. And Dictionary implements this interface. So why there is such implemenation that I image breaks interface convention?

(Also the symbol type structure which I image the idea behind Dictionary seems to have the convention that the method should not throw the exception.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IDictionary` is not generic, for example a `HashTable` implements it. So a `HashTable`'s key and it's value are objects, hence it can ([and indeed does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.item(v=vs.100).aspx)) return `null` if a key was not found. A [`IDictioanary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zyxt2e2h(v=vs.100).aspx)'s value can be a value type, hence it has no "error"-value like `null` which can be returned instead.

Comment: When you say "key is an object", do you mean "value"? Because that's what's returned from `Item`, not the key.